# Weekdays as terms - How to order taxonomy terms by ID in admin panel?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, order

I created a custom taxonomy using following code.

```
add_action( 'init', 'schedule_day_tax_func' );
function schedule_day_tax_func() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'schedule_day_taxonomy',
        'schedule',
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Day',
            'query_var' => true,
            'orderby'  => 'ID', 
        )
    );
}
```

after I added some terms from the admin panel, the TERMS displayed in `alphabetica`l order in admin panel.

[image: img]

I want those in orderby `ID` or by the `entered` order. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method #1 - Modifying the query arguments

If we want to modify the *term order* for the `schedule_day_taxonomy` term checklist, on the single `schedule` cpt edit screen, then we can use the following setup:

```
add_action( 'load-post.php', function()
{
    add_filter( 'wp_terms_checklist_args', 'wpse_terms_checklist_args' );
} );

function wpse_terms_checklist_args( $args )
{         
    // Target the 'schedule' custom post type edit screen
    if( 'schedule' === get_current_screen()->id )
        add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'wpse_terms_args', 10, 2 );
    return $args;
}

function wpse_terms_args( $args, $taxonomies )
{
    // Target the 'all' tab in the 'schedule_day_taxonomy' terms check list 
    if(
           isset( $args['get'] )
        && 'all' === $args['get']
        &&  isset( $taxonomies[0] )
        && 'schedule_day_taxonomy' === $taxonomies[0]
    ) {
        // Modify the term order
        $args['orderby'] = 'ID';  // <-- Adjust this to your needs!
        $args['order']   = 'ASC'; // <-- Adjust this to your needs!

        // House cleaning - Remove the filter callbacks
        remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );        
        remove_filter( 'wp_terms_checklist_args', 'wpse_terms_checklist_args' );
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Another possibility would be to combine this into a single `get_terms_args` filter callback.

To get the following day order:

```
Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat
```

we could modify the corresponding term slugs and use:

```
// Modify the term order
$args['orderby'] = 'slug';  
$args['order']   = 'ASC';
```

### Method #2 - Re-ordering the query results

If we don't want to modify the slug, then here's another approach.

We can re-order the resulting terms array, in the same order as the localized weekdays.

```
add_filter( 'wp_terms_checklist_args', function( $args )
{         
    add_filter( 'get_terms', 'wpse_get_terms', 10, 3 );
    return $args;
} );

function wpse_get_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args )
{
    if(     isset( $taxonomies[0] )
        && 'schedule_day_taxonomy' === $taxonomies[0]
        && 'schedule' === get_current_screen()->id
    ) {
        $newterms = [];
        foreach( (array) $GLOBALS['wp_locale']->weekday as $day )
        {
            foreach( (array) $terms as $term )
            {
                if( $term->name === $day )
                    $newterms[] = $term;
            }
        }
        remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
        if( 7 === count( $newterms ) )
            $terms = $newterms;
    }
    return $terms;
}
```

We could also replace

```
$GLOBALS['wp_locale']->weekday
```

with a custom weekdays array, ordered in a custom way.

Here's the *English* version:

[image: English]

and here's the *Icelandic* version:

[image: Icelandic]

### Method #3 - Custom SQL ordering

We could modify the SQL ordering with the `get_terms_orderby` filter, with a `CASE/WHEN/THEN` setup.

Hopefully you can adjust this to your needs.

Comment: Epic answer as always birgire

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at this link: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34996

```
public function pre_get_terms( $query ) {
  $meta_query_args = array(
    'relation' => 'AND', // Optional, defaults to "AND"
    array(
        'key'     => 'order_index',
        'value'   => 0,
        'compare' => '>='
    )
  );
  $meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query_args );
  $query->meta_query = $meta_query;
  $query->orderby = 'position_clause';
}
```

The answer was in the comment of @eherman24. all you need to adapt is adding an action `pre_get_terms` and then use the above function.